# AdminLTE 3.0 how to know if CardWidget is currently open or closed?

Tags: adminlte

How can I tell if an [AdminLTE 3.0 CardWidget](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/javascript/card-widget.html) is currently collapsed or expanded? Is checking for the class "collapsed-class" the only way? Seems like there should be a property or method I could call. This works:

`var isCollapsed = $('#myCard').hasClass("collapsed-card");`

however that brings me to my 2nd question: if I'm in an event callback for expanding or collapsing the CardWidget (because I want to save it's state for the next time the user comes to this page):

```
$('#myCard').on('expanded.lte.cardwidget', function() {
    mySavePrefs();
});
$('#myCard').on('collapsed.lte.cardwidget', function() {
    mySavePrefs();
});
```

The the state of the CardWidget is it's current state (at the start of the event), where what I want to do is save the post-event state.

For example, if the widget is expanded and you click the button to collapse it, then the collapsed.lte.cardwidget event handler is called. But in that handler if you get the state of the widget it says it's expanded, even though it's about to be collapsed once the handler leaves.

I guess what I need is an event handler that is called *after* the event is finished being processed. Does that exist?